# Can an enlarged Broom of Flying carry more weight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, creature-size, flight

Excerpts from [Enlarge Person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/):

> This spell causes instant growth of a humanoid creature, doubling its
> height **and multiplying its weight by 8**...
>
> ...**All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly enlarged by the spell**...
>
> ...**Other magical properties are not affected by this spell.**
> Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged
> creature’s possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon)
> instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown and
> projectile weapons deal their normal damage.
> **Magical properties of enlarged items are not increased by this spell.**

A standard [Broom of Flying](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/broom-of-flying/) can carry up to 400 lbs. Enlarge Person octuples the target's weight. Assuming a Medium sized humanoid is riding the broom, and said humanoid weighs more than 50 lbs, would casting Enlarge Person (or a similar spell) on them make them plummet out of the air, despite their broom getting enlarged alongside them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A bigger *broom* doesn't automatically carry more weight

The rules are inflexible on this point. The [*broom of flying*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/broom-of-flying/) can carry at most 400 pounds before falling out of the air. Additional magic on the *broom* that changes the *broom*'s size will not give it more carrying capacity. I don't even know of a spell that will directly increase the carrying capacity of an item.

Try lowering your weight for *enlarge person*. Core material like the spell [*lighten object*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lighten-object/) and the third-party spell [*alter weight*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/3rd-party-spells/ascension-games/alter-weight/) might help, too.